# How to iterate over second level of an Array to get a single array as final result?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get a final Array from the second level of my array

```
Students =
[{
  "name":"Ashish",
  "lastname":"Boora",
  "detail":[
            {"id":1,"sid":3,"pid":5},
            {"id":2,"sid":4,"pid":6},
            {"id":7,"sid":8,"pid":9}
          ]
},{
  "name":"Harsh",
  "lastname":"Deep",
  "detail":[
            {"id":11,"sid":13,"pid":15},
            {"id":12,"sid":14,"pid":16},
            {"id":17,"sid":18,"pid":19}
          ]
},{
  "name":"Rajat",
  "lastname":"Sharma",
},
{ 
  "name":"Sumit",
  "lastname":"Verma",
  "detail":[
            {"id":21,"sid":23,"pid":25},
            {"id":22,"sid":24,"pid":26},
            {"id":27,"sid":28,"pid":29}
          ]
}]
```

I want to get final output as array of all the id in detail of each element of the array as

```
ids = [1,2,7,11,12,17,21,22,27]
```

Please note that there are some elements in the main array for which the key 'detail' is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourArray
    .flatMap((person) => // Map over every person
        person.detail // Get detail array, if it exists
          ?.map((detail) => detail.id)) // Return id for each detail entry
    .filter(Number) // Removing undefined entries caused by people with no `details`
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Comment: Fair point, will edit

Comment: It works for me in the second edit, I was getting undefined earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) solves your issue:

```
const ids = students.flatMap(student => student.detail || []).map(detail => detail.id);
```

Here `students.flatMap(...)` will iterate over all students. For each student we get their `detail`, if it's not present we'll use an empty array `person => person.detail || []`. This will result in one large array containing the `detail` elements of all `students`.

We then iterate over this list and map each `detail` to its `id` with `.map(detail => detail.id)`. This produces a list with just detail ids.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the name, I appreciate your focus on every tiny thing. The thing is this is not the code from real project, i just took this as an example to describe things more easily.

Comment: Even examples should have good names. An example is a lot easier to understand if the variable names are descriptive and code is expressive.

Comment: Sure, will be careful next time.